# Will not filter prime out and giving the wrong factor number in c

Tags: c

I tried to filter out a prime number. For instance, I input 7; the output will be 7 is odds and the factor number is 2 and 3. If I enter 55, the factor numbers are 6 and 9. It always calculate a result with the number I give minus one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int n,factor1,factor2;
bool factor(int number,int *firstFactor,int *secondFactor);
bool isPrime,prime;
int main(){

  printf("Please give a number, we will tell you if it is a prime number: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  isPrime=factor(n, &factor1,&factor2);
  if(isPrime)
  {printf("The number %d is prime\n",n);
  }
      else{
          printf("%d is odd.The possible factor is %d and %d.\n",n,factor1,factor2);

      }

  return 0;
  }


bool factor(int number,int *firstFactor,int *secondFactor){
      int i;
      i=sqrt(number);

      for(i; i>1;i--){
       if(number%i==0){ break;
     }

      *firstFactor=i;
      *secondFactor=number/i;
      }

      //while(!prime);
      //prime=false;

 return(prime==1);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing two statements in the factor function. 
Firstly define a variable prime.

```
int prime=1;
```

Secondly in the loop you need to assign prime as 0 before the break statement

```
prime=0
```

Your final code becomes

```
bool factor(int number,int *firstFactor,int *secondFactor){
      int i;
      i=sqrt(number);

    int prime=1;
      for(i; i>1;i--){
       if(number%i==0){ 
        prime=0;
        *firstFactor=i;
        *secondFactor=number/i;
        break;
        }
      }

      //while(!prime);
      //prime=false;

 return(prime==1);
 }
```

Edit :

Also the statements where you are finding factors will never be called as the loop breaks as soon as if statements runs. Try moving that inside the if or try breaking the loop after those statements

Comment: If you can edit your posted code to represent you statement at the end, then this would be correct. It would also be nice to format your posted code.

Comment: Thanks guys! I have solved the issue according your reguestion.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you never initialize or change value of **prime**.

**prime** here is boolean so you can give values `prime=false;` and `prime=true;`
instead of `prime=1;` or `prime=0;`

[Solution in online IDE](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/eVZ4kLtteh)

Try this code.It works :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int n,factor1,factor2;
bool factor(int number,int *firstFactor,int *secondFactor);
bool isPrime,prime;
int main(){

  printf("Please give a number, we will tell you if it is a prime number: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  isPrime=factor(n, &factor1,&factor2);
  if(isPrime)
  {printf("The number %d is prime\n",n);
  }
      else{
          printf("%d is odd.The possible factor is %d and %d.\n",n,factor1,factor2);

      }

  return 0;
  }


bool factor(int number,int *firstFactor,int *secondFactor){
      int i;
      i=sqrt(number);

      // Give a default value to prime
      prime=true;

      for(i; i>1;i--){
       if(number%i==0){
           printf("%d ",i);
           // Change value of not prime 
           prime=false;
           break;
         }
      }
      *firstFactor=i;
      *secondFactor=number/i;
// Return value Back
 return(prime);
 }
```